# Joins on composite key using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, composite-key

I am not getting how to write Hibernate criteria query to achieve the result similar to the result obtained by below SQL query. Please suggest me what are all steps need to be followed to achieve the result.

```
SELECT PRODUCT.PRODUCTNAME, ITEM.ITEMNAME 
FROM PRODUCT_ITEM
JOIN PRODUCT
   ON PRODUCT_ITEM.ID = PRODUCT.ID
JOIN ITEM
   ON PRODUCT_ITEM.ID = ITEM.ID
```

Above is my Sql Query to fetch the product_name and item_name. It is working correctly.
I tried get the same result using HIBERNATE CRITERIA QUERY.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ProductItem.class,"pi");
criteria.createAlias("pi.pk.product", "pip");
criteria.createAlias("pi.pk.item", "pii");
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("pip.id")).add(Projections.property("pii.id")));

List<Object[]> list = criteria.list();
```

i am getting error saying

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2147)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2028)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2023)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:95)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
at checkComposite.main(checkComposite.java:38)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "pip1_"
Position: 8
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:304)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1668)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2144)
```

Here my ENTITYS are as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {
private Integer id;
private String name;
private List<ProductItem> productItems = new LinkedList<ProductItem>();

public Item() {
}

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.item")
public List<ProductItem> getProductItems() {
    return this.productItems;
}

public void setProductItems(List<ProductItem> productItems) {
    this.productItems = productItems;
}
}
```

Product Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

private Integer id;
private String name;
private List<ProductItem> productItems = new LinkedList<ProductItem>();

public Product() {
}

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.product")
public List<ProductItem> getProductItems() {
    return this.productItems;
}

public void setProductItems(List<ProductItem> productItems) {
    this.productItems = productItems;
}
}
```

PRODUCT_ITEM entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_item")
@AssociationOverrides({
@AssociationOverride(name = "pk.item", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")),
@AssociationOverride(name = "pk.product", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
    })
public class ProductItem {

private ProductItemPk pk = new ProductItemPk();

@EmbeddedId
private ProductItemPk getPk() {
    return pk;
}

private void setPk(ProductItemPk pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
}

@Transient
public Item getItem() {
    return getPk().getItem();
}

public void setItem(Item item) {
    getPk().setItem(item);
}

@Transient
public Product getProduct() {
    return getPk().getProduct();
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    getPk().setProduct(product);
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    ProductItem that = (ProductItem) o;

    if (getPk() != null ? !getPk().equals(that.getPk()) : that.getPk() != null) return false;

    return true;
}

public int hashCode() {
    return (getPk() != null ? getPk().hashCode() : 0);
}
}
```

Embedable Class is as below.

```
@Embeddable
public class ProductItemPk implements Serializable {

private Item item;
private Product product;

@ManyToOne
public Item getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(Item item) {
    this.item = item;
}

@ManyToOne
public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    ProductItemPk that = (ProductItemPk) o;

    if (item != null ? !item.equals(that.item) : that.item != null) return false;
    if (product != null ? !product.equals(that.product) : that.product != null)
        return false;

    return true;
}

public int hashCode() {
    int result;
    result = (item != null ? item.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (product != null ? product.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query to:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ProductItem.class,"pi");
criteria.createAlias("pi.pk", "pipk");
criteria.createAlias("pipk.product", "pip");
criteria.createAlias("pipk.item", "pii");
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("pip.id")).add(Projections.property("pii.id")));
List<Object[]> list = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "pip2_"
  Position: 8
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
 ......

Comment: You need to log your SQL queries and post them to the question.

Comment: Hibernate: select pip2_.product_id as y0_, pii3_.item_id as y1_ from product_item this_
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: SQL query is mentioned at the begining of the question

Comment: I mean the SQL query that's generated by Hibernate, the full query, so I can figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: Hibernate: select emp1_.first_name as y0_, emp.employee_id as     empid, count(order_id) as cnt from orders this_ inner join employees emp1_ on this_.employee_id=emp1_.employee_id group by  emp.employee_id having count(ord.order_id)>3

Comment: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "emp"